# CodeIgniter, Smarty and Form Helper. Does not trigger form_validation->run()

Tags: codeigniter, smarty, codeigniter-form-helper

I am using CodeIgniter with Smarty. The problem I encountered is when using Form helper. I used [the code found here](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Form-helper-with-Smarty).

So when I open and close the form tag actually using CI native `form_open` and `form_close` then after the form submission `form_validation->run()` is still always `false`.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->register();
}

function register()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Register';
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules()
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        //the form has not been submitted or there are errors
        $this->parser->parse("register", $data); 
    }
    else
    {
        //validated and submitted
        die();
    }
}

function login()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Login';
    $this->parser->parse("login", $data);
}
}
```

And the template is

```
Registration page
{form url='user/register'}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="reg_username" id="reg_username"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="reg_password" id="reg_password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="reg_firstname" id="reg_firstname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="reg_lastname" id="reg_lastname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="submitted"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>

{form}
```

I expect `die()` command to be executed when the form is submitted by it is not - please advice me what am I doing wrong?

P.S. The method I used to integrate Smarty into CodeIgniter is https://github.com/Vheissu/Ci-Smarty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must [set at least one validation rule](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrules) in your `register()` method. For example, something like:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('reg_username', 'Username', 'required');
```

From the [Form_validation class documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html):

> Since you haven't told the Form Validation class to validate anything yet, it returns FALSE (boolean false) by default. The `run()` function only returns `TRUE` if it has successfully applied your rules without any of them failing.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, works like a charm now. And thanks for the link, I'd better check the documentation. But do I get it right that form_validation->run() cannot be used just to check whether the form was submitted or not? For example, there will be some forms in my project that will not have any required fields or other conditions whatsoever. I do not want to use isset($_REQUEST['submit']) in some places and form_validation->run() in others.

Comment: @VladimirHraban: I'm glad it's working for you. You are correct - `run()` does **not** determine if a form was submitted, but rather if your validation rules were applied successfully. An alternative for checking if a form was submitted (perhaps a more "CodeIgniter way") is to use `if($this->input->post())` - it will return `FALSE` if there are no POST array items and `TRUE` if there are (You can read more via the [Input class documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html))

Comment: Thank you! This saves me a lot of time